# Can I use `recur` in this implementation of function composition in Clojure?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, clojure, tail-recursion

Consider this simple-minded recursive implementation of `comp` in Clojure:

```
(defn my-comp
  ([f]
   (fn [& args]
     (apply f args)))
  ([f & funcs]
   (fn [& args]
     (f (apply (apply my-comp funcs) args)))))
```

The right way to do this, I am told, is using `recur`, but I am unsure how `recur` works. In particular: is there a way to coax the code above into being `recur`able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**evaluation 1**

First let's visualize the problem. `my-comp` as it is written in the question will create a deep stack of function calls, each waiting on the stack to resolve, blocked until the the deepest call returns -

```scm
((my-comp inc inc inc) 1)
((fn [& args]
     (inc (apply (apply my-comp '(inc inc)) args))) 1)

(inc (apply (fn [& args]
                (inc (apply (apply my-comp '(inc)) args))) '(1)))

(inc (inc (apply (apply my-comp '(inc)) '(1))))

(inc (inc (apply (fn [& args]
                     (apply inc args)) '(1))))

(inc (inc (apply inc '(1)))) ; ⚠️ deep in the hole we go...
(inc (inc 2))
(inc 3)
4
```

**tail-recursive my-comp**

Rather than creating a long sequence of functions, this `my-comp` is refactored to return a *single* function, which when called, runs a `loop` over the supplied input functions -

```scm
(defn my-comp [& fs]
  (fn [init]
    (loop [acc init [f & more] fs]
      (if (nil? f)
          acc
          (recur (f acc) more))))) ;  tail recursion
```

```scm
((my-comp inc inc inc) 1)
;; 4
```

```scm
((apply my-comp (repeat 1000000 inc)) 1)
;; 1000001
```

**evaluation 2**

With `my-comp` rewritten to use `loop` and `recur`, we can see *linear iterative* evaluation of the composition -

```
((my-comp inc inc inc) 1)
(loop 1 (list inc inc inc))
(loop 2 (list inc inc))
(loop 3 (list inc))
(loop 4 nil)
4
```

**multiple input args**

Did you notice ten (10) `apply` calls at the beginning of this post? This is all in service to support multiple arguments for the first function in the `my-comp` sequence. It is a mistake to tangle this complexity with `my-comp` itself. The caller has control to do this if it is the desired behavior.

Without any additional changes to the refactored `my-comp` -

```scm
((my-comp #(apply * %) inc inc inc) '(3 4)) ; ✅ multiple input args
```

Which evaluates as -

```scm
(loop '(3 4) (list #(apply * %) inc inc inc))
(loop 12 (list inc inc inc))
(loop 13 (list inc inc))
(loop 14 (list inc))
(loop 15 nil)
15
```

**right-to-left order**

Above `(my-comp a b c)` will apply `a` first, then `b`, and finally `c`. If you want to reverse that order, a naive solution would be to call `reverse` at the `loop` call site -

```scm
(defn my-comp [& fs]
  (fn [init]
    (loop [acc init [f & more] (reverse fs)] ; ⚠️ naive
      (if (nil? f)
          acc
          (recur (f acc) more)))))
```

Each time the returned function is called, `(reverse fs)` will be recomputed. To avoid this, use a `let` binding to compute the reversal just once -

```scm
(defn my-comp [& fs]
  (let [fs (reverse fs)] ; ✅ reverse once
    (fn [init]
      (loop [acc init [f & more] fs]
        (if (nil? f)
            acc
            (recur (f acc) more))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

a way to do this, is to rearrange this code to pass some intermediate function back up to the definition with recur.

the model would be something like this:

```
(my-comp #(* 10 %) - +)

(my-comp (fn [& args] (#(* 10 %) (apply - args)))
           +)

(my-comp (fn [& args]
             ((fn [& args] (#(* 10 %) (apply - args)))
              (apply + args))))
```

the last my-comp would use the first my-comp overload (which is `(my-comp [f])`

here's how it could look like:

```
(defn my-comp
  ([f] f)
  ([f & funcs]
   (if (seq funcs)
     (recur (fn [& args]
              (f (apply (first funcs) args)))
            (rest funcs))
     (my-comp f))))
```

notice that despite of not being the possible `apply` target, the `recur` form can still accept variadic params being passed as a sequence.

```
user> ((my-comp (partial repeat 3) #(* 10 %) - +) 1 2 3)
;;=> (-60 -60 -60)
```

notice, though, that in practice this implementation isn't really better than yours: while `recur` saves you from stack overflow on function creation, it would still overflow on application (somebody, correct me if i'm wrong):

```
(apply my-comp (repeat 1000000 inc)) ;; ok

((apply my-comp (repeat 1000000 inc)) 1) ;; stack overflow
```

so it would probably be better to use `reduce` or something else:

```
(defn my-comp-reduce [f & fs]
  (let [[f & fs] (reverse (cons f fs))]
    (fn [& args]
      (reduce (fn [acc curr-f] (curr-f acc))
               (apply f args)
               fs))))

user> ((my-comp-reduce (partial repeat 3) #(* 10 %) - +) 1 2 3)
;;=> (-60 -60 -60)

user> ((apply my-comp-reduce (repeat 1000000 inc)) 1)
;;=> 1000001
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a good answer above, but I think the original suggestion to use `recur` may have been thinking of a more manual accumulation of the result.  In case you haven't seen it, `reduce` is just a very specific usage of `loop/recur`:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core  tupelo.test))

(defn my-reduce
  [step-fn init-val data-vec]
  (loop [accum init-val
         data  data-vec]
    (if (empty? data)
      accum
      (let [accum-next (step-fn accum (first data))
            data-next  (rest data)]
        (recur accum-next data-next)))))

(dotest
  (is=  10 (my-reduce + 0 (range 5)))    ; 0..4
  (is= 120 (my-reduce * 1 (range 1 6)))  ; 1..5 )
```

In general, there can be any number of loop variables (not just 2 like for reduce). Using `loop/recur` gives you a more "functional" way of looping with accumulated state instead of using and `atom` and a `doseq` or something. As the name suggests, from the outside the effect is quite similar to a normal recursion w/o any stack size limits (i.e. tail-call optimization).

---

**P.S.**  As this example shows, I like to use a `let` form to very explicitly name the values being generated for the next iteration.

**P.P.S.**  While the compiler will allow you to type the following w/o confusion:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core  tupelo.test))

(defn my-reduce
  [step-fn accum data]
  (loop [accum accum
         data  data]
     ...))
```

it can be a bit confusing and/or sloppy to re-use variable names (esp. for people new to Clojure or your particular program).

---

### Also

I would be remiss if I didn't point out that the function definition itself can be a `recur` target (i.e. you don't need to use `loop`).  Consider this version of the factorial:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core  tupelo.test))

(defn fact-impl
  [cum x]
  (if (= x 1)
    cum
    (let [cum-next (* cum x)
          x-next   (dec x)]
      (recur cum-next x-next))))

(defn fact [x] (fact-impl 1 x))

(dotest
  (is= 6 (fact 3))
  (is= 120 (fact 5)))
```